# while loop wont end, despite false condition

Tags: c++, while-loop, switch-statement, conditional-statements

I'm trying to use switch inside a loop, with an option to `exit (3)`.

If I immediately press 3 then everything is OK and the while loop ends.

If I enter any of the other options first, and on the second time I press '3', the loop continues one more time, and I need to press '3' one more time for exit.

I've tried to do some debugging and it shows that 'exit' is equal to true but the loop is executed anyway.

```
enum mainIndex { products = 1, clients, mainExit };

void Menue::start() {
    bool exit = false;
    int option;
    while (!exit) {
        cin >> option;
        // swich menue
        switch (option)
        {
        case products:
            prodMenue();
            break;
        case clients:
            clientMenue();
            break;
        case mainExit:
            exit = true;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Error" << endl;
            break;
        }; // end switch
    }
}
```

edit:

```
enum prodIndex { prodAdd = 1, prodEditName, prodEditPrice, prodPrint, prodExit };
enum clientIndex { clientAddClient = 1, clientEdit, clientAddToCart, clientPurchase, clientExit };

void Menue::prodMenue() {
    bool exit = false;
    int optionProd;
    while (!exit)
    {
        cin >> optionProd;
        switch (optionProd)
        {
            case prodAdd:
                addProduct();
                break;
            case prodEditName:
                editProductPrice();
                break;
            case prodEditPrice:
                editProductPrice();
                break;
            case prodPrint:
                cout << market.getProducts();
                break;
            case prodExit:
                exit = true;
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Error" << endl;
                break;
        }// end switch
    }// end while
    start();
}

void Menue::clientMenue() {
    bool exit = false;
    int optionClient;
    while (!exit)
    {
        cin >> optionClient;
        switch (optionClient)
        {
        case clientAddClient:
            addClient();
            break;
        case clientEdit:
            editClient();
            break;
        case clientAddToCart:
            addProdToCart();
            break;
        case clientPurchase:
            buyCart();
            break;
        case clientExit:
            exit = true;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Error" << endl;
            break;
        }// end switch
    }// end while
    start();
}



/***************************************************************************
*Menue class:                                                              *
*contains a user interface to control the store                            *
***************************************************************************/
class Menue {
    Store market;

    /***********************************************************************
    *function name: prodMenue                                              *
    *The Input: input from user - number 1-5 (loop)                        *
    ***********************************************************************/
    void prodMenue();

    /***********************************************************************
    *function name: clientMenue                                            *
    *The Input: input from user - number 1-5 (loop)                        *
    ***********************************************************************/
    void clientMenue();

    /***********************************************************************
    *function name: addProduct                                             *
    *The Input: input from user - product serial name and price            *
    *The Function operation: creating new product if not in market         *
    ***********************************************************************/
    void addProduct();

    /***********************************************************************
    *function name: editProductName                                        *
    *The Input: input from user - product serial and new name              *
    *The Function operation: search for a product and edit its name if exis*
    ***********************************************************************/
    void editProductName();

    /***********************************************************************
    *function name: editProductPrice                                       *
    *The Input: input from user - product serial and new price             *
    *The Function operation: search for a product and edit its price if exi*
    ***********************************************************************/
    void editProductPrice();

    /***********************************************************************
    *function name: addClient                                              *
    *The Input: input from user - client id, name, adress, phone and credit*
    *The Function operation: creating new costumer if not in market        *
    ***********************************************************************/
    void addClient();

    /***********************************************************************
    *function name: editProduct                                            *
    *The Input: input from user - client id, name, adress, phone and credit*
    *The Function operation: editing existing product if in market         *
    ***********************************************************************/
    void editClient();

    /***********************************************************************
    *function name: editClientFull                                         *
    *The Input: ptr to costumer, id, name, adress, phone and credit        *
    *The Function operation: creating new product if not in market         *
    ***********************************************************************/
    void editClientFull(Costumer* client, const string &name,
        const string &adress, const string &phone, const string &credit);

    /***********************************************************************
    *function name: addProdToCart                                          *
    *The Input: input from user - costumer id and product serial           *
    *The Function operation: creating new product if not in market         *
    ***********************************************************************/
    void addProdToCart();

    /***********************************************************************
    *function name: buyCart                                                *
    *The Input: input from user - client id                                *
    *The Function operation: cleaning cart print it to screan + total price*
    ***********************************************************************/
    void buyCart();
public:
    /***********************************************************************
    *function name: default Ctor                                           *
    ***********************************************************************/
    Menue() {};

    /***********************************************************************
    *function name: default Dtor                                           *
    ***********************************************************************/
    ~Menue() {};

    /***********************************************************************
    *function name: start                                                  *
    *The Input: input from user - number 1-3 (loop)                        *
    ***********************************************************************/
    void start();
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "menue.h"

int main() {
    Menue navigat;
    navigat.start();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [I can not replicate the problem](http://ideone.com/O6sgz0). The problem is most likely in the code that you don't show us.

Comment: The problem will be in `prodMenue` and/or `clientMenue`.

Comment: ive added prodMenue and clientMenue - they work on same principle.

Comment: I can't still replicate the problem. Can you show us your main() and start() functions. And the exit condition in your given code is 5 not 3.

Comment: the problem is only in the start menue where the exit condition is 3. 
ill aad the class menue and the main

Answer (score 0):

Calling `start();` again from the `clientMenue()` and `prodMenue()` functions is what is causing your problem. Since these functions are already called from the `start()` function there is no need to call the `start()` function from inside these function because thy will return to `start()` when they are done.

As an example what you are doing is:

```
    (1st)Start()---calls--->clientMenue()---calls---->(2nd)Start()
So  (2nd)start() --return to-->clientMenu()---return to--->(1st)start()
```

Assuming you display the clientMenue() once and decide to exit from Start(),that is why you need to give your exit condition twice for start, one for each start() function. If you display either of the Client or Product menu by calling the clientMenue() or prodMenue() function N number of times without choosing to exit from start() then by the time you decide to exit from start() you have to enter your exit condition N+1 times.

So remove the call to the `start()` function from the `clientMenue()` and `prodMenue()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

on my experience,

if i use switch in the while loop cpu is lock down and there is no responding to any user or system input.

here is an Example is Lock my cpu and not print to screen "breaking the while loop", why is this happening i don't know but when i input wait function to case 1
loop is break down truely.

```
int condition = 1;
bool loop = true;
while(loop ){

    switch(condition){

       case 1:
         wait(1); // if you put this with any msecond, loop can be break
         cout << "Enter 2 for exit" << endl;
         cin >> condition;

       break;

       case 2:

         cout << "Exiting";
         loop = false;

       break;

       default:

       break;

    }
}

cout << "breaking the while loop" << endl;
```